# How to get local system time for all zones in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass my local system time to server using new Date() function.But when i pass it is being converted to UTC time.The problem is I'm not able to get the correct time I am passing.It is reducing 5.30 hrs to the system time.If i change the time to some other zone,time is being reduced to 2.30 hrs and so on.I have searched many solutions but none of them worked . I want to have the time in following format : **2017-08-03T07:28:09.514Z** .

Any suggestions would be helpful.Thanks

Comment: use moment.js. It handles all of your needs

Comment: `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` this is give you the timezone

Answer (score 2):

Using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is indeed a good advice. The code should look like this:

```
var date = new Date()
date = moment(date).add(3, 'hours').add(30, 'minutes')

date.toDate()
```

I'm a little concerned about the right format of the object but it should work

Answer (score 1):

`2017-08-03T07:28:09.514Z` is time in UTC, as defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), because of `Z` at the end of the string. So, if your local time is Indian Standard Time, it is exactly UTC+05:30, and you'll have 5 hours and a half less in UTC. It is actually quite a good idea to send time to server in UTC because any decent server application (language) should be able to process it and convert to time in any time zone.

Another good option to send time is [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is measured in seconds and is also in UTC. `new Date().getTime()` returns value in milliseconds, so divide it by 1000, and you get a single Number, which is easy to transmit, store, and use (to convert to the date-time object).

Comment: Agree about using server time, but what to do if you want to return range of documents created only in July for example. Docs that were created by user from India since 00:00 in August 01 till 05:29 August 01 will be missing because of using UTC server time. You'd stil need to take timezone offset in account

Comment: Sometimes knowledge of user timezone is essential. However, in case user requests aforementioned documents, both start and end dates could be sent to a server in UTC. But if user has incorrect system timezone set, or outdated tzdata, an error might appear when working with some abstract dates, not "now".

Comment: True. I just wanted to notice sometimes developer still needs to manipulate dates because of timezone offsets before sending them from/to server